# Tridion 2011 with DD4T - no MetaData fields available on Component entity

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, dd4t

I'm using Tridion 2011 (with DD4T, feeding an MVC webapp).

It seems that MetaData fields for Multimedia Components (specified on the Metadata tab of my Images Schema in Tridion) are not populating the corresponding property on the DD4T "Component" object. e.g. `LinkedComponentFields[0].MetadataFields` is empty and `Multimedia.AltText` is null.

Specifically the field I'm after is the AltText. But as the entire MetadataFields collection is empty on the Component, it's obviously not pulling through any metadata properties. i have tried using TemplateBuilder to set parameters in the Component Template (I set "resolve width and height" to yes, and the MergeAction to Merge) - this did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for your first SDL Tridion related post. Please consider committing to the Area 51 proposal using your SO id at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2 - We really need everyone's help.

Comment: Do you see anything in the Template Builder log at the DEBUG level? You should see messages like: "start retrieving tcm metadata fields", "add fields: found 1 fields"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possibly caused by the linklevel. By default, links are followed for one level from the page or component that you are publishing.
You can increase this by adding a parameter to the template invocation, called linklevel. Try it with a value of 2 first, then increase until it works.